# Deletar uma classe inteira e tudo que está nela de um HTML carregado via ajax

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho duas págias em HTML:

index.html:

```
    <div class="topo">
       topo
    </div>
    <div id="viewdata">
       <div class="conteudo">
          Essa é a home
       </div>
    </div>
```

noticia.html

```
    <div class="topo">
       topo
    </div>
    <div id="viewdata">
       <div class="conteudo">
          Essa é a notícia
       </div>
    </div>
```

Estou fazendo as trocas entre as páginas com AJAX. dessa forma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "noticia.html",
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#viewdata').html(data);
});
```

Mas eu queria pegar apenas tudo que está na classe 'conteudo' no arquivo noticia.html, e não todo o resto, porque da forma que estou fazendo o resultado está sendo esse:

```
    <div class="topo">
       topo
    </div>
    <div id="viewdata">
       <div class="topo">
          topo
       </div>
       <div id="viewdata">
          <div class="conteudo">
             Essa é a notícia
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Ou seja, o arquivo gerado fica com algumas classes duplicadas. Eu até poderia excluir o topo com replace, mas na prática a classe topo é gigante, assim como outras classes, ficaria inviável. Existe alguma solução?

Comment: Vc quer pegar a div .conteudo ou só o que tem dentro? Vc quer inserir na div #viewdata ou na classe .conteudo?

Comment: @Sam Eu quero pegar a classe conteudo da noticia.html e inserir ela dentro da viewdata da index.html, ou seja, apagaria o conteúdo da index.html e chegaria uma nova classe conteudo da noticia.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) onde você pode buscar no arquivo requisitado um elemento específico:

```
$("#viewdata").load("noticia.html .conteudo");
```

O código acima irá substituir todo o HTML interno da div `#viewdate` pela div `.conteudo` vinda da página `noticia.html`.